# Error cierre de etiqueta - Angular

Tags: html5

```
<!--BARRA NAVEGACION-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-1 fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Argentina-Programa #YoProgramo</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarColor02"
      aria-controls="navbarColor02"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Acerca de mi</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#experience">Experiencia</a>
        </li>
        <p></p>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#education">Educacion</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Proyectos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="px-3" style="font-size: 1.8em; color: rgb(182, 172, 172)">

        <i class="fab fa-facebook me-2" ></i>  
        <i class="fab fa-instagram me-2"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin me-2"></i>
      
      </div>


      <div class="desp">
      
        <button class="hamburger hamburger--arrowalt" type="button" id="hideText_btn">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
          </span>
        </button>
        

          <div class="ingreso">
            <span id="hideText">
            Usauario <input class = "usuario" type="email" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="name@example.com"> 
            Contraseña <input class = "usuario" type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
            </span>
            <button
            class="btn btn-outline-light me-2 p-2align-self-center" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt" ></i> Login
          </div>

                  </button> 
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
 
</nav>
```

Error del button: Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tagsngtsc(-995002)

Error del div: Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tagsngtsc(-995002)

Comment: Revisa el orden en el que cierras las etiquetas. Has cerrado un `div` antes de cerrar el `button`.

Comment: Listo! muchas gracias!!